# matlab/octave - Generalized matrix multiplication

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave, matrix-multiplication

I would like to do a function to generalize matrix multiplication. Basically, it should be able to do the standard matrix multiplication, but it should allow to change the two binary operators product/sum by any other function.

The goal is to be as efficient as possible, both in terms of CPU and memory. Of course, it will always be less efficient than A*B, but the operators flexibility is the point here.

Here are a few commands I could come up after reading [various](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5582943/1121352) [interesting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24222365/1121352) [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20014812/boolean-matrix-multiplication-in-matlab):

```
A = randi(10, 2, 3);
B = randi(10, 3, 4);

% 1st method
C = sum(bsxfun(@mtimes, permute(A,[1 3 2]),permute(B,[3 2 1])), 3)
% Alternative: C = bsxfun(@(a,b) mtimes(a',b), A', permute(B, [1 3 2]))

% 2nd method
C = sum(bsxfun(@(a,b) a*b, permute(A,[1 3 2]),permute(B,[3 2 1])), 3)

% 3rd method (Octave-only)
C = sum(permute(A, [1 3 2]) .* permute(B, [3 2 1]), 3)

% 4th method (Octave-only): multiply nxm A with nx1xd B to create a nxmxd array
C = bsxfun(@(a, b) sum(times(a,b)), A', permute(B, [1 3 2]));
C = C2 = squeeze(C(1,:,:)); % sum and turn into mxd
```

The problem with methods 1-3 are that they will generate n matrices before collapsing them using sum(). 4 is better because it does the sum() inside the bsxfun, but bsxfun still generates n matrices (except that they are mostly empty, containing only a vector of non-zeros values being the sums, the rest is filled with 0 to match the dimensions requirement).

What I would like is something like the 4th method but without the useless 0 to spare memory.

Any idea?

Comment: why not try something using sparse matrices so that you will save on memory allocation? you may be able to get that to work. [spfun](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spfun.html) is similar to bsxfun, but for sparse matrices so I am assuming it keeps memory usage pretty low in the background as well.

Comment: Already done, and indeed the 4th method should be able to take profit of sparseness, but unluckily it won't work with Octave as its bsxfun operator is not sparse friendly, so everything will be stored in memory.

Comment: Your 3rd and 4th examples do not work. Your 1st example does not work on MATLAB R2010b and older.

Comment: the other question I have is, how large are the matrices you are dealing with that you are so concerned about memory.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis: Thank you for your feedback, yes indeed the 3rd and 4th work only on Octave. One more reason to find an alternative, because the problem with the 4th method is exactly the problem I want to fix: the output dimension is not correct.

Comment: @MZimmerman6: Between n*10E4 and n*10E5 (where n is usually between 20 and 6400) for each matrix, and this should be able to manage bigger matrices. But they are very sparse, so I can heavily use memory tricks to enhance the computation.

Comment: First thing that struck me was `sum(bsxfun(@times,permute(A,[1 3 2]),permute(B,[3 2 1])),3)`, but then it won't be efficient for sparse cases.

Comment: @Divakar: yes indeed, I have tried something but anyway I now think this is impossible without using at least one for loop, simply because the output dimension must be the same as the input dimension (or with singleton expansion it must be the dimension > 1 between the two inputs). Thus it's impossible to set the correct output dimension for a direct matrix multiplication (with sum inside the bsxfun). I now think that only a loop is possible in this case...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a slightly more polished version of the solution you posted, with some small improvements.

We check if we have more rows than columns or the other way around, and then do the multiplication accordingly by choosing either to multiply rows with matrices or matrices with columns (thus doing the least amount of loop iterations).

[image: A*B]

***Note***: This may not always be the best strategy (going by rows instead of by columns) even if there are less rows than columns; the fact that MATLAB arrays are stored in a [column-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order#Column-major_order) in memory makes it more efficient to slice by columns, as the elements are stored consecutively. Whereas accessing rows involves traversing elements by [strides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stride_of_an_array) (which is not cache-friendly -- think [spatial locality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference)).

Other than that, the code should handle double/single, real/complex, full/sparse (and errors where it is not a possible combination). It also respects empty matrices and zero-dimensions.

```
function C = my_mtimes(A, B, outFcn, inFcn)
    % default arguments
    if nargin < 4, inFcn = @times; end
    if nargin < 3, outFcn = @sum; end

    % check valid input
    assert(ismatrix(A) && ismatrix(B), 'Inputs must be 2D matrices.');
    assert(isequal(size(A,2),size(B,1)),'Inner matrix dimensions must agree.');
    assert(isa(inFcn,'function_handle') && isa(outFcn,'function_handle'), ...
        'Expecting function handles.')

    % preallocate output matrix
    M = size(A,1);
    N = size(B,2);
    if issparse(A)
        args = {'like',A};
    elseif issparse(B)
        args = {'like',B};
    else
        args = {superiorfloat(A,B)};
    end
    C = zeros(M,N, args{:});

    % compute matrix multiplication
    % http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Inner_product
    if M < N
        % concatenation of products of row vectors with matrices
        % A*B = [a_1*B ; a_2*B ; ... ; a_m*B]
        for m=1:M
            %C(m,:) = A(m,:) * B;
            %C(m,:) = sum(bsxfun(@times, A(m,:)', B), 1);
            C(m,:) = outFcn(bsxfun(inFcn, A(m,:)', B), 1);
        end
    else
        % concatenation of products of matrices with column vectors
        % A*B = [A*b_1 , A*b_2 , ... , A*b_n]
        for n=1:N
            %C(:,n) = A * B(:,n);
            %C(:,n) = sum(bsxfun(@times, A, B(:,n)'), 2);
            C(:,n) = outFcn(bsxfun(inFcn, A, B(:,n)'), 2);
        end
    end
end
```

### Comparison

The function is no doubt slower throughout, but for larger sizes it is orders of magnitude worse than the built-in matrix-multiplication:

```
        (tic/toc times in seconds)
      (tested in R2014a on Windows 8)

    size      mtimes       my_mtimes 
    ____    __________     _________
     400     0.0026398       0.20282
     600      0.012039       0.68471
     800      0.014571        1.6922
    1000      0.026645        3.5107
    2000       0.20204         28.76
    4000        1.5578        221.51
```

[image: mtimes_vs_mymtimes]

Here is the test code:

```
sz = [10:10:100 200:200:1000 2000 4000];
t = zeros(numel(sz),2);
for i=1:numel(sz)
    n = sz(i); disp(n)
    A = rand(n,n);
    B = rand(n,n);

    tic
    C = A*B;
    t(i,1) = toc;
    tic
    D = my_mtimes(A,B);
    t(i,2) = toc;

    assert(norm(C-D) < 1e-6)
    clear A B C D
end

semilogy(sz, t*1000, '.-')
legend({'mtimes','my_mtimes'}, 'Interpreter','none', 'Location','NorthWest')
xlabel('Size N'), ylabel('Time [msec]'), title('Matrix Multiplication')
axis tight
```

---

### Extra

For completeness, below are two more naive ways to implement the generalized matrix multiplication (if you want to compare the performance, replace the last part of the `my_mtimes` function with either of these). I'm not even gonna bother posting their elapsed times :)

```
C = zeros(M,N, args{:});
for m=1:M
    for n=1:N
        %C(m,n) = A(m,:) * B(:,n);
        %C(m,n) = sum(bsxfun(@times, A(m,:)', B(:,n)));
        C(m,n) = outFcn(bsxfun(inFcn, A(m,:)', B(:,n)));
    end
end
```

And another way (with a triple-loop):

```
C = zeros(M,N, args{:});
P = size(A,2); % = size(B,1);
for m=1:M
    for n=1:N
        for p=1:P
            %C(m,n) = C(m,n) + A(m,p)*B(p,n);
            %C(m,n) = plus(C(m,n), times(A(m,p),B(p,n)));
            C(m,n) = outFcn([C(m,n) inFcn(A(m,p),B(p,n))]);
        end
    end
end
```

---

### What to try next?

If you want to squeeze out more performance, you're gonna have to move to a C/C++ MEX-file to cut down on the overhead of interpreted MATLAB code. You can still take advantage of optimized BLAS/LAPACK routines by calling them from MEX-files (see [the second part of this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6440839/97160) for an example). MATLAB ships with [Intel MKL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Math_Kernel_Library) library which frankly you cannot beat when it comes to linear algebra computations on Intel processors.

Others have already mentioned a couple of submissions on the File Exchange that implement general-purpose matrix routines as MEX-files (see [@natan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24302803/97160)'s answer). Those are especially effective if you link them against an optimized BLAS library.

Comment: Nice trick with the M switch, however shouldn't it be M < N instead of M > N (since we want to reduce the number of loops?), and shouldn't C(m,:) = outFcn(bsxfun(inFcn, A(m,:), B), 1); be C(m,:) = outFcn(bsxfun(inFcn, A(:,m), B), 1); instead to fully use the column-major order (even more important with sparse matrices)? Also a minor note, your code uses a few functions that don't work with Octave 3.8.1 (args{:}, superiorfloat).
However I indeed got a bit more speed using your code so you have the closest answer right now.

Comment: @user1121352: 1) yes my bad, should be the other way around with `M<N`. I'll fix it. 2) no it's correct as is (I think you missed the transpose in `A(m,:)'`). The idea is to horizontally concatenate rows of `A` "multiplied" by matrix `B`. 3) I didn't test it with Octave, but it should be easy to adapt the code. The syntax `zeros(.., 'like',X)` has not yet made it into Octave, you could probably replace it with a similar `zeros(.., class(X))` (no gonna pick on up the sparsity attribute though).

Comment: ... As for the `superiorfloat` call, you could replace it with a manual check to pick the appropriate type between `single`/`double` (this is because of [the way data types propagate in MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2014a/matlab/matlab_prog/valid-combinations-of-unlike-classes.html) when combining different numeric classes)

Comment: In previous comment I should have said "vertically concatenate" instead of "horizontally concatenate". I had had also flipped the description in the code comments. It's fixed now :/ I also added a note about traversing by rows vs. by columns...

Comment: Thank's for the precisions, but are you really sure it wouldn't be better to access A'(:,m) instead of A(m,:)' so that A gets sliced by column instead of strided? In the same vein, C could be transposed and then could be filled using C(:,m) instead of C(m,:)? Anyway I award you the bounty, but last thing I will try is to use the LAPACK . If that doesn't work, I will accept your answer.

Comment: @user1121352: Like I explained, it is not always clear-cut. The cost of transposing `A` and `C` before and after the loop could outweigh the benefit of accessing by columns. I guess it depends on the size of the input matrices... We could for instance change the `if`-condition to something like `if 2*M<N` to justify slicing by row (or any other multiplier you feel is appropriate). Best way to decide is to run tests and see which one gives better running times on average :)

Answer (score 3):

Why not just exploit [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)'s ability to accept an arbitrary function?

```
C = shiftdim(feval(f, (bsxfun(g, A.', permute(B,[1 3 2])))), 1);
```

Here

- `f` is the **outer function** (corrresponding to *sum* in the matrix-multiplication case). It should accept a 3D array of arbitrary size `m`x`n`x`p` and operate along its columns to return a `1`x`m`x`p` array.
- `g` is the **inner function** (corresponding to *product* in the matrix-multiplication case). As per `bsxfun`, it should accept as input either two column vectors of the same size, or one column vector and one scalar, and return as output a column vector of the same size as the input(s).

This works in Matlab. I haven't tested in Octave.

---

**Example 1**: Matrix-multiplication:

```
>> f = @sum;   %// outer function: sum
>> g = @times; %// inner function: product
>> A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6];
>> B = [10 11; -12 -13; 14 15];
>> C = shiftdim(feval(f, (bsxfun(g, A.', permute(B,[1 3 2])))), 1)
C =
    28    30
    64    69
```

Check:

```
>> A*B
ans =
    28    30
    64    69
```

---

**Example 2**: Consider the above two matrices with

```
>> f = @(x,y) sum(abs(x));     %// outer function: sum of absolute values
>> g = @(x,y) max(x./y, y./x); %// inner function: "symmetric" ratio
>> C = shiftdim(feval(f, (bsxfun(g, A.', permute(B,[1 3 2])))), 1)
C =
   14.8333   16.1538
    5.2500    5.6346
```

Check: manually compute `C(1,2)`:

```
>> sum(abs( max( (A(1,:))./(B(:,2)).', (B(:,2)).'./(A(1,:)) ) ))
ans =
   16.1538
```

Comment: Thank's for your detailed answer, but it is quite similar to what Divakar proposed above, and the problem is the memory explosion because bsxfun cannot do the sum-products per singleton expansion (instead of producing the whole expansion and then summing in the 3rd dimension). For example, try with this matrix on Octave: A = randi(2, 1000, 500)-1; this will produce an index overflow. Also, this doesn't work with sparse matrices as it's not possible to permute into the 3rd dimension if sparse.

Answer (score 1):

Without diving into the details, there are tools such as [mtimesx](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25977-mtimesx-fast-matrix-multiply-with-multi-dimensional-support) and [MMX](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37515-mmx-multithreaded-matrix-operations-on-n-d-matrices) that are fast general purpose matrix and scalar operations routines. You can look into their code and adapt them to your needs. 
It would most likely be faster than matlab's bsxfun.

Comment: +1 going native with C/C++ code is definitely the way to go here

Comment: I agree this would be the best solution speed-wise and memory-wise, but I'm not sure you can pass functions as arguments for the GMM, although I guess one can define the most common operators inside the mex file and pass a string as argument to choose. Also there is a LAPACK direct call FEX that may fit the bill here, without even having to rewrite any MEX code: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/16777-lapack/content/lapack.m

Comment: I tried the LAPACK FEX library but it doesn't work with Octave, I don't know about latest MatLab versions. I found another interesting project: the **Mc2For** project which aims to produce Fortran 95 code from MatLab function sourcecodes: http://www.sable.mcgill.ca/mclab/matlab_fortran.html

Answer (score 0):

After examination of several processing functions like bsxfun, it seems it won't be possible to do a direct matrix multiplication using these (what I mean by direct is that the temporary products are not stored in memory but summed ASAP and then other sum-products are processed), because they have a fixed size output (either the same as input, either with bsxfun singleton expansion the cartesian product of dimensions of the two inputs). It's however possible to trick Octave a bit (which does not work with MatLab who checks the output dimensions):

```
C = bsxfun(@(a,b) sum(bsxfun(@times, a, B))', A', sparse(1, size(A,1)))
C = bsxfun(@(a,b) sum(bsxfun(@times, a, B))', A', zeros(1, size(A,1), 2))(:,:,2)
```

However do not use them because the outputted values are not reliable (Octave can mangle or even delete them and return 0!).

So for now on I am just implementing a semi-vectorized version, here's my function:

```
function C = genmtimes(A, B, outop, inop)
% C = genmtimes(A, B, inop, outop)
% Generalized matrix multiplication between A and B. By default, standard sum-of-products matrix multiplication is operated, but you can change the two operators (inop being the element-wise product and outop the sum).
% Speed note: about 100-200x slower than A*A' and about 3x slower when A is sparse, so use this function only if you want to use a different set of inop/outop than the standard matrix multiplication.

if ~exist('inop', 'var')
    inop = @times;
end

if ~exist('outop', 'var')
    outop = @sum;
end

[n, m] = size(A);
[m2, o] = size(B);

if m2 ~= m
    error('nonconformant arguments (op1 is %ix%i, op2 is %ix%i)\n', n, m, m2, o);
end


C = [];
if issparse(A) || issparse(B)
    C = sparse(o,n);
else
    C = zeros(o,n);
end

A = A';
for i=1:n
    C(:,i) = outop(bsxfun(inop, A(:,i), B))';
end
C = C';

end
```

Tested with both sparse and normal matrices: the performance gap is a lot less with sparse matrices (3x slower) than with normal matrices (~100x slower).

I think this is slower than bsxfun implementations, but at least it doesn't overflow memory:

```
A = randi(10, 1000);
C = genmtimes(A, A');
```

If anyone has any better to offer, I'm still looking for a better alternative!